# List all the default site content types and site columns in sp 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, site-column

I want to get all the default site content types and site columns in sp 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer these blogs.

1. [Site Columns](https://andynoon.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/list-of-standard-site-columns/)
2. [Site Content Type](http://sharepointgoose.blogspot.in/2010/11/enter-post-title.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at [SPBuiltInContentTypeId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltincontenttypeid_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) type. It contains static fields that returns SPContentTypeID for all build-in CTs:
AdminTask, Announcement, BasicPage, BlogComment, BlogPost, CallTracking, Contact, Discussion, Document, DocumentSet, DocumentWorkflowItem, DomainGroup, DublinCoreName, Event, FarEastContact, Folder, GbwCirculationCTName, GbwOfficialNoticeCTName, HealthReport, HealthRuleDefinition, Holiday, IMEDictionaryItem, Issue, Item, Link, LinkToDocument, MasterPage, Message, ODCDocument, Person, Picture, Resource, ResourceGroup, ResourceReservation, RootOfList, Schedule, ScheduleAndResourceReservation, SharePoint, SummaryTask, System, Task, Timecard, UDCDocument, UntypedDocument, WebPartPage, WhatsNew, Whereabouts, WikiDocument, WorkflowHistory, WorkflowTask, XMLDocument, XSLStyle